# What's the Best Way to Navigate Silverlight XAML in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, xaml

When editing Silverlight XAML in Visual Studio 2008, the Document Outline panel is not supported by Microsoft.

1) Any helpful tip for navigating a deep XAML markup hierarchy without the benefit of the Document Outline tool?

2) Is this supported in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Unfortunately, there's not (that I know of). The only option would be to also use Expression Blend which provides a much easier XAML editting environment.
2. I believe so, yes.

Comment: Definately agree. If you're doing anything halfway professional with XAML get Blend. VS2010RC supports document outline currently.

Comment: +1 on the answer and Graeme's comment. VS2010 RTM is only a few short weeks away (April 12), and the RC is working great (and supports Silverlight 4 RC, released earlier this week at MIX).